# Utilizing vespa only as vector database and not embedder

Tags: embedding, nearest-neighbor, vespa, vector-database

I have utilized Vespa when trying to store embedding embedded using some model defined in services.xml file. However, I intend to generate embeddings externally and store them in Vespa and utilize it for nearest neighbor search for explicitly providing query vectors.

However, I face issue defining schema for such use-case.  [image: Schema]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To fix this**: Move the embedding field inside the document block in the schema.
(Also, the document type should be named "neighbors", not "schema".)

**Explanation**: Your embedding field is not sourcing another field and mutating it, as when the embedding happens in the indexing statement, it is just a value of the document. Those must be defined inside the document block as they define the document type that you can write and get.

Comment: you have deep knowledge of Vespa.  I cannot find such documentaiton at Vespa website.  Where can I find such information? For query, how can I create my own embedding using my own models?

Comment: Creating a document field which is a vector is definitely part of the documentation. To do the embedding yourself either call an api for it or use your own model. Sounds like you'd be better off letting Vespa do this though.